# Apply a function to two vectors the "R" way?

Tags: r

There are two vectors x and y. If x contains an `NA` I want the `NA` to be replaced by a value from "y" with the corresponding index. Here is some example code that works:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,5)
y <- c(6,7,8,9,10)

combineVector <- function(x,y)
{
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (is.na(x[i]) && !is.na(y[i])){
      x[i] = y[i]
    }
  }  
   return (x) 
  }
combineVector(x,y)
# [1] 1 2 3 9 5
```

I could have written this in almost any programming language. Is there a more "R" way to perform this task?

Comment: in this example `pmin(x, y, na.rm = TRUE)` would also work

Comment: While that will work in this example, the code doesn't in principle do what the OP asked for and would fail if any element of y is less than its corresponding element of x.  Since that would often be the case in various use cases, you should not suggest that as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,5)
y <- c(6,7,8,9,10)

x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
```

See the above.  using is.na() on x returns a logical vector where it is TRUE for the NA elements of x.  Using these in the selector for X and Y will select only those NA elements.  Using it in assignment will replace the NA elements from x with the corresponding ones from Y.

That will be much faster than looping as the vector gets large.

Comment: Without reassignment, you can also do `replace(x,is.na(x),y[is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
```

By subsetting the `x` vector with `is.na(x)` you will be assigning *only* those values of `x` which are `NA` to the corresponding indices in the `y` vector.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a new vector taking `x` and `y` as input, you can use the `ifelse` function:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,NA,NA)
y<-c(6,7,8,9,NA)
ifelse(is.na(x), y, x)
# [1]  1  2  3  9 NA
```